# Changing week+day(39+3) variable into either week or days in R

Tags: r

Im working with a pregnancy-lenght [factor] variable that is given in number of weeks+days(39+3) and I need to be able to work with a whole number that i can compare between groups and calculate the mean. So either 276 days (37*7+3) or 37,43 weeks (37+(3/7)). 
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The two (whole days vs. fractional weeks) are entirely equivalent, but you should probably go for fractional weeks as a) weeks are easier to relate to and b) fractional weeks are continuous, whole days are discrete, and continuous data is often easier.

Comment: a) is a matter of opinion..., and b) not true, since the fractional weeks is always in steps of 1/7, and therefore not continuous. You can never get data for 3,125 weeks, only for 3 and 3,1429, and so on... so it is not more continuous than using the days.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to play with `lubridate` to kind of address this.

Assuming your variable in like `a+b` where `a` is in weeks and `b` is days.

```
library(lubridate)
s <- "39+3"
s <- gsub("$", "d", gsub("\\+", "W ", s)) #Add W and d to denote Weeks and days
s
[1] "39W 3d"
period(s) #Convert into a period format
[1] "276d 0H 0M 0S"
as.numeric(period(s), "days") #Change that to noofdays
[1] 276
```

Answer (score 0):

some fiddlng with `data.table`..

**sample data**

```
library( data.table )
set.seed(123)
DT <- data.table( pregnancy.length = paste0( sample(20:42, 100, replace = TRUE), 
                                             "+",
                                             sample(1:6, 100, replace = TRUE) ), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
```

**code**

```
#first, split the pregnancy-length on the `+`-sign  
DT[, c("weeks", "days") := lapply( tstrsplit( pregnancy.length, "\\+"), as.numeric )]
#then caluculate weeks, days, or both
DT[, `:=`( week.total = weeks + days / 7, day.total = weeks * 7 + days )]
```

**output

```
head(DT)
#    pregnancy.length weeks days week.total day.total
# 1:             26+4    26    4   26.57143       186
# 2:             38+2    38    2   38.28571       268
# 3:             29+3    29    3   29.42857       206
# 4:             40+6    40    6   40.85714       286
# 5:             41+3    41    3   41.42857       290
# 6:             21+6    21    6   21.85714       153
```